# How to define =removeRecursive within Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

How do I define the following so that it removes all 'familyName'

```json
{
  "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
  "spec": {
    "*": "=removeRecursive('familyName')"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi You can use **remove** operation to remove instead of **modify-overwrite-beta** ?

```json
{
  "operation": "remove",
  "spec": {
    "familyName": ""
  }
}
```